# что загружается вперед js или source video?

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Подскажите пожалуйста что загружается вперед, видео из тега video или js, просто сейчас очень долго прогружается js. В плане, листнеры на события только через 20сек присваивывются, думаю проблема в видео, которые много весят.

Comment: Если в коде JS стоит перед VIDEO и у него (JS) нет аттрибутов async или defer, то гарантированно пока не загрузится и не выполнится код JS - все что далее в коде, включая VIDEO, - будет считаться несуществующим. Если порядок обратный или у JS установлены аттрибуты async или defer, то невозможно предсказать что будет загружено в первую очередь.

Answer (score 0):

Страница обрабатывается сверху вниз. Т.е если у вас разметка идет вперед то она обрабатывается раньше js. Если у вас идет вперед js то и соответственно рзметка будет позже.

Comment: Это не совсем верно! Существуют атрибуты, которые могут запускать асинхронные загрузки JS, минуя, как вы выразились, порядок "сверху вниз".